# "return document.readyState" in Jmeter WebDriver Sampler, in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver, jmeter-plugins

I am quite new in Selenium and WDS in Jmeter, so please help me.
I can not write a code, wait until the entire page loads. I found something like "`return document.readyState`", but I can not do it in my code. So I said - I'm quite green in this.

I have "`wait`" in my code but it is not enought.

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium); //WebDriver classes
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait); //WebDriver classes
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 10000);
var conditions = org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart(); //captures sampler's start time
WDS.sampleResult.getLatency();
WDS.log.info("Sample started");

WDS.browser.get('https://somethingsomething');
wait.until(conditions.elementToBeClickable(pkg.By.xpath("//a[@href='x']")));
WDS.log.info("Sample ended - navigated to somethingsomething");

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so you can consider switching to Groovy and writing normal [explicit waits](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) - there is a shit ton of examples over the web, just in case if you need one more:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://example.com')
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 15)

ExpectedCondition<Boolean> documentReady = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return WDS.browser.executeScript("return document.readyState")
                .toString().equalsIgnoreCase("COMPLETE");
    }
};
wait.until(documentReady)
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

If you **have to go for JavaScript** - it is still possible to call Java functions via i.e. [JavaAdapter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java#The_JavaAdapter_Constructor) object, example code would be something like:

```
load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js")
var wait = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 15)
WDS.browser.get('http://example.com')

function Invoker(obj) {
    return new JSAdapter() {
        __has__: function(name) {
            return true;
        },
        __get__: function(name) {
            return function() {
                return obj.invoke(name, arguments);
            }
        }
    }
}

var r = {
    invoke: function(name, args) {
        return WDS.browser.executeScript("return document.readyState") == 'complete'
    }
};
wait.until(new JavaAdapter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition, Invoker(r)))
```

More information:

- [Using Java From Scripts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)

Comment: Thank you :) 
I already wrote somtehing like this and it is works ! In groovy of course.


ExpectedCondition<Boolean> documentReady = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return WDS.browser.executeScript("return document.readyState")
                .toString().equalsIgnoreCase("COMPLETE");
    }
};
wait.until(documentReady)